# Package springboot without web project to a runnable Jar and run by java -jar but @Scheduled method not working

Tags: java, spring-boot, jar, scheduler

I'm building a spring boot project without web server,because I don't need it. I have run it by using `terminal` java -jar )

I wrote some method with annotation @Schedule like:

```
@Scheduled(initialDelay = 1000, fixedRate = 10000)
    public void goGetAll() {
        log.info("HELLO I AM RUNNING THIS SCHEDULE ");
    }
```

And when I try to run this project by `eclipse` the  executed output is
like that:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KDFQV.png)

Here is another situation when package this project to jar and run it by cmd
here is my Main method

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("main run");
    SpringApplication.run(MyClass.class, args);
    System.out.println("main run2");
}
```

I'm able to see main run on my screen

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using `println` instead of `log.info`. It should work then.

Comment: does`t work  
actually i think that about "main run2" didnt show  maybe meaned my spring boot didt init successfully , and then my friend find a  maybe right solution for me , and I try by it then @SChedule run will, i wlll share about it later~~~

Answer (score 0):

this my friend`s answer~
he sugget me to check this web
http://www.appsdeveloperblog.com/run-spring-boot-app-from-a-command-line/

I find this web use mvn cmd to package project to jar, and then I follow it way to package,and i find ide packages jar and mvn package jar are different inside inside
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iYP2d.png)

left side is mvn package jar , right sid is eclipse packeagejar,
there forder structur is different,and that is reason,
 I run java -jar to mvn package jar then all schedule system.out.println msg successed show up .